# JXBrowser Bundle: This license can only be used with Bound to class name

Tags: eclipse, osgi, osgi-bundle, jxbrowser

I'm trying to bundle JXBrowser into an OSGI plugin but I keep getting an invalid license error.  The error output with my teamdev.licenses file info is:

```
-- Product name: JxBrowser
-- Licensed version: 6.x
-- Licensed to: 
-- License type: Development
-- License bound to product: Bound to class name
-- Generation date: Apr 12, 2017
-- Expiration date: NEVER
-- License info: Open Source Project
-- Current date: Aug 24, 2017
JxBrowser license check failed: This license can only be used with Bound to class name
```

I have JXBrowser successfully loading in eclipse via Maven, but I need to know how to bind the license to my classname, in this case `org.brettjsettle.internal.OpenExternalAppTask`. The JXBrowser website says:

> The license.jar file that contains JxBrowser license isn't an OSGi bundle, so we recommend that you extract the teamdev.licenses file from the license.jar archive and put it into META-INF folder of the jxbrowser.jar file, so that license checker could find it.

Since I'm fetching JXBrowser through Maven, I just pasted teamdev.licenses in my src/main/resources/META-INF folder. I've tried adding lines to the licenses file but that results in `Signature is not valid`

Am I missing something? How do I bind the license to a class name?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message in the output indicates that the license you have is bound to a specific class name which isn't included into your application class path.
When you obtained the license file from JxBrowser Sales Team, you should've provided them with the specific class in your application.
Please make sure that that class is in your application class path.

Comment: Thanks.  My boss had forgotten to send that to me in the first place. Got it working now.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to unzip the JXBrowser jar and manually add the licenses file to the META-INF directory, repackage the jar and install it to my maven locally. I guess I was just hoping that would be less work.

For anyone else, you can unzip the jar, add your license file, rejar it with `jar cvfM jxbrowser-X.X.jar ./*` from within the unzipped dir. Then install it to your local maven with:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=jxbrowser-6.14.2.jar -DgroupId=com.teamdev.jxbrowser -DartifactId=chromium -Dversion=6.14.2 -Dpackaging=jar
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=jxbrowser-mac-6.14.2.jar -DgroupId=com.teamdev -DartifactId=jxbrowser.mac -Dversion=6.14.2 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Hope this was helpful to someone!